# PyCurl taking a long time to perform

Tags: python, performance, pycurl

After I've installed a new, clean system on my PC (Windows 10 x64), I'm encountering some issues with the pycurl lib for python (of course).

I was trying this on Python 2.7 and 3.4 - doesn't make any difference.

It takes a long time to respond after I send the request (24secs), no matter what the target is, even 'localhost'.

Piece o'code:

```
import pycurl, time
from io import BytesIO

buf = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buf)
t = time.clock()
c.perform()
print("elapsed time: {} sec".format(time.clock() - t))
c.close()

body = buf.getvalue()
```

I've tried the same on my VPS machine (ubuntu) and it works beautifuly.

Comment: `elapsed time: 0.00925174318082 sec` ... (tested in windows py2.6 and py2.7) ...

Comment: yeah, you don't say :(

Comment: what happens if you try `http://www.freecodecamp.com/the-fastest-web-page-on-the-internet` ? i get about 0.12

Comment: the link you gave me doesn't work, I mean it says that it could not be found. 

But as I said, it doesn't matter what host it is, it's the function's (lib's) fault.

Comment: hmm it seems to have changed some characters ... when i copied and pasted the url ... try it on a different pc ... im pretty sure i did not install any special libcurl I just ran `pip install pycurl` ...

Comment: I've just found out that it's the NS lookup that's lagging so much. When I set a IP address as url it works normally. Someone has any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced the same issue, and as you indicated in your comment, the issue was the DNS lookup which took an extraordinary amount of time. I managed to work around this by forcing pycurl to use a specific DNS server (in this case Google's):

```
c.setopt(pycurl.DNS_SERVERS, '8.8.8.8')
```

However, by warned that I have seen crashes on some linux systems when executing this code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this next time I'll be using pycurl.